# R data.table to vector using variable name as data.table name?

Tags: r, datatable

I want to use a variable as the df name but cant figure out how.
I can do it this way

```
 'vector2 <- df$columname'
```

If i want to do it in a loop looking at different data tables i cant do it.
vector1 is the names of my data.tables that i want to put the column data into a vector2.

I want the loop to do this

```
 'vector2 <- one$columname'
 'vector2 <- two$columname'
 'vector2 <- three$columname'
```

changing the data.table name each time it goes through the loop keeping column name the same.

```
'vector1<- c("one","two","three")
for(i in vector1) {
vector2 <- vector1$columname
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated in OP's post, use either `mget` (returns the values of all the objects into a named list) or `get` (for a single element - can be used within `for` loop) to return the values of the dataset names i.e. 'one', 'two', 'three'

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(vector1), function(x) x$columname)
```

If it should be a single vector

```
vector2 <- unlist(lst1)
```

---

In a `for` loop, it can be done as

```
for(i in vector1) vector2 <- get(i)$columname
```

This replaces 'vector2' in each iteration and gets the last columnname i.e. from 'three'.  If we need to create a single vector

```
vector2 <- c()
for(i in vector1) vector2 <- c(vector2, get(i)$columname)
```